# How to programmatically enforce this equation

Tags: algorithm, simulation, simulate

I'm trying to simulate vehicle power-train using component block and connectors like modelling software does. So I can connect flywheel to clutch, clutch to gearbox, gearbox to differential, differential to shaft, and shaft to wheel.

A gear component in OpenModelica has this equation:

`0 = ratio * flange_a.tau + flange_b.tau`

Tau is a flow type variable for torque. Torque can flow from flywheel down to wheel, and from wheel back to the engine.

My question is how to programmatically enforce this equation. So I can have flange_a.tau carrying torque from the engine and flange_b.tau carrying reaction torque from the wheels and still satisfy the equation.

As programming is assignment based, if I do

`flange_b.tau = -ratio * flange_a.tau`

it satisfies the equation but overwrite the reaction torque from the wheel.

I hope this make sense.

Comment: are you asking how to assert that a certain equation is true?

Comment: how are you checking when the equation is true? are the values changing in a loop, and u are checking everytime?

Comment: @Haris No. It shows up in the vehicle behavior and wheels are not in sync with reaction from the ground.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to test whether the equation holds true, replace the assignment operator (=) with the equality operator (==).
But given the references to Modelica, etc, I suspect you're hoping to determine the tau values (as part of a larger model) that will solve the equation? Tools like OpenModelica rearrange your equation-based model into a set of differential equations which are then solved for a given state.

Comment: I intend to handle torque flowing from both direction, engine and wheel in one update iteration. So each component determine what the output torque is from the two input torques it receives. Maybe I should just do two iteration in one loop, first do update from the engine down to wheel, then do a second update from the wheel to engine.

Comment: @FarolanFaisal Doesn't torque always flow from higher to lower? So whichever of `flange_a` or `flange_b` carries the more torque will drive the other. (And the difference of them will accumulate as stress on the component, which matters if the component can only withstand a finite amount of stress.)

Comment: @biziclop Thank you very much. I don't realize that basic law. Clearly I overlook this and thought it has to be a complex formula with all this derivation things and what not. :)

Comment: @FarolanFaisal I was just asking, I'm not an expert in these matters at all, so my assumption is probably wrong. But the rule should be something similar.